# inversion: sing as you do

Tags: inversion

Is the following sentence correct, on the model of "try as you may"?

> **Sing as you do** today, he is never going to be happy with you.

> **Live as I do** in Japan, I will never be treated as a local.

Comment: living and singing, not simple present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an informal construction, and there doesn't seem to be clear consensus on exactly what is happening grammatically (possibly some kind of ellipsis). But it is something that people say. A bare infinitive ("try", "sing", etc) is used without either a subject or the infinitive marker "to". The construction involves two clauses, the first giving a condition or hypothetical action, and the second the hypothetical outcome.

It can be done either with "and" linking the clauses ("Sing as you do today and he is never going to be happy with you"), or with a pause (comma). Examples with "and" are perhaps more common, or at least easier to search for, such as the song "[Come as you are](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/3159033/Peter+Wolf/Come+as+You+Are)" by Peter Wolf: "Come as you are and we'll have a ball."

**Meaning**

It's best interpreted as an elliptical construction:

> Sing as you do today, he is never going to be happy with you

is equivalent to

> If you sing as you sing today, he is never going to be happy with you.

(In the above "if" might be replaced by "As long as" or "While" or some other conjunction that sets up a conditional expression.)

There are other variants. "Try as you might, you won't do it" is also a conditional which has dropped various elements. But here it is rather idiomatic ("No matter how hard you try").

**Grammar**

While it could be elliptical, it might be viewed as an imperative or imperative-like construction. Compare "Try all you like, you'll never beat me." This could be taken as an instruction, telling the person to try, but warning that they'll never succeed. I don't think all of the above constructions can be interpreted as imperatives, but it may be an influence on the construction. (For a more clearly imperative use see e.g. the Eminem track "[Say What You Say](https://genius.com/Eminem-say-what-you-say-lyrics)" or Pink's "Do What U Do").

There's a quote attributed to TS Eliot (although I've not found the source), "To become what you are not, behave as you do not" - this could be inverted to "behave as you do not, to become what you are not". This is again imperative-like.

You can compare the use of the bare infinitive as a pseudo-subject in "Talk to him was what I did" or "Obey was all they could do" (see this [question in ELU SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503096/talk-to-him-is-what-i-did). This might be considered an example of inversion, rather than having a bare infinitive as a subject, but it's debatable.

The bare infinitive has various usages like this which are informal, but not uncommon. So I wouldn't use it in written English, but you may hear it or similar things - although I'd prefer the version with "and": "Sing as you do today and he is never going to be happy with you."

Answer (score 0):

Your sentences don't work. You need to use constructions such as:

> If you sing as you are doing today...
>
> Even though I live in Japan...

Comment: Why is "Try as I may, I cannot get the door open" correct and the others incorrect?

Comment: "Living in Japan as I do, I have become accustomed to Japanese food" is possible,  but I don't think it would ever be used in contrast to something negative as you have done. We use _[Verb] as I may/might_ and _[Adjective] as I am_... in that way, but not just any inverted phrase.

Comment: "Sing as you **will** today..." would work.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The sentences seem perfectly reasonable to me, if not particularly likely to be spoken colloquially. You could make an argument that it's a rare enough form that it's best avoided outside fixed idioms like "try as you may", but I think it's a sound grammatical construction, that you could probably find examples of in more "flowery" prose.

Comment: @IMSoP Singing as you do today. The simple present does not work here.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think it is the simple present, it's an infinitive attached to a modal: "I might try" -> "try as I might, ..." seems related to "that may be" -> "be that as it may, ...". I think "singing as you do today" is a different construction - perhaps with an implied subject, as in "[when you are] singing as you do today"? Interesting that they're so close, though - you could probably even say "trying as I might..." My grammatical theory is not strong enough to go beyond hunches, though.

Comment: @IMSoP Of course it is simple present: Sing as you do, singing as you are. But there is also the actual modals, as you say: Try as you might, Try as you should etc.

Comment: Is it revealing that adjuncts can intervene in some of these but not others? "Try as I might today, I can't get it to work" is fine but "Try today as I might, I can't get it to work" sounds funny. But "Singing today as you do" is fine. "Bake today though I must" seems acceptable (but rather flowery).

Comment: @IMSoP I came to realize overnight that this as + verb can get very complicated and I don't plan to cover every case.

Comment: "try as I/you may/might" is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/try+as+I+may), featured in dictionaries of idioms, so not a general pattern.